# Сложность с возвращением значения метода с неопределенным числом аргументов

Tags: java, ооп, методы

Прохожу методы с неопределенным числом аргументов, пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы можно было рассчитать зарплату с премией и без `monthSalary`. Однако на строке

```
monthSalary = monthSalary+prize;
```

в консоли возникает ошибка: `';' expected`. Как это можно обойти и что тут неправильно?

```
public static class Salary {


    public static int calcSalary(int payment, int hours, int... prize) {
        int monthSalary = payment * hours;
        monthSalary = monthSalary + prize;
        return monthSalary;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Salary aprilSalary = new Salary();
        Salary maySalary = new Salary();


        System.out.println("My salary in April is " + aprilSalary.calcSalary(500, 160, 3000));


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Ничего что выводимая ошибка совершенно другая? https://ideone.com/jse0qW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял, раз вы передаете неограниченное количество аргументов в метод, то в самом методе вы хотите получить их сумму, в этом случае метод нужно переписать так:

```
public static int calcSalary(int payment, int hours, int... prize) {
    return payment * hours + IntStream.of(prize).sum();
}
```

Тоже самое можно седлать с помощью цикла:

```
public static int calcSalary(int payment, int hours, int... prize) {
    int monthSalary = payment * hours;
    for (int p : prize) monthSalary += p;
    return monthSalary;
}
```

В любом случае нужно понимать, что в методе calcSalary переменная int... prize является не просто целочисленной переменной (int), а массивом (множеством) целочисленных переменных (знак троеточия - это и есть массив). Поэтому просто суммировать данную переменную не получится, к массивам неприменимы математические операции. Придется перебирать массив и совершать нужное действие с каждой отдельной переменной , находящейся в массиве, что , собственно, и сделано с помщью цикла либо стрима.

Answer (score 0):

`prize` - это массив. Поэтому как минимум надо брать `prize[0]`

А вообще судя по коду у вас лишняя закрывающая фигурная скобка